# New android apps are working fine on old phones but not on new phones

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I found out a few apps I made in the past 2 months are not working on new phones, but working fine on old phones. I tested some of my old apps that are working fine on both new and old phones. I must be missing something related to the code, I only have basic skills related to coding and want to fix these apps.

```
BuildTools = "29"
        MinSdk = 16
        TargetSdk = 29
        CompileSdk = 29
```

In my Build.Gradle:App section, I added this code, because without this code, I was not able to generate a signed bundle.

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You say it's not working anymore, what is not working?

Comment: Not exactly easy to determine what the issue is without more info. You could be using a deprecated API for example.

Try running the app on an emulator and see what errors occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android 10 update there are many modifications in permissions and notifications, for example you need notification channel to generate notifications android Oreo but it will work fine on other devices, You need to verify all permissions and modifications are done with new devices and you need to update code according to it.

Comment: This is it, library found needing to be updated, so now have to take care of that.